# Launching a specific web page from iOS home screen

Tags: ios, icon, web-browsing

I want to create an app icon on my iOS home screen that launches a particular web page in a browser when it is tapped. In other words, it should look visually like an app, but I don't want to have to code an app. I don't want to have to launch a browser and open a bookmark each time I want to visit that web page.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari, the default browser available in iOS has a feature that lets you [add a website bookmark to your Home Screen](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph42ab2f3a7/ios).

The bookmark visually looks like an app icon and when tapped, opens the webpage in Safari. The website favicon is used to represent the app icon. However, unlike Safari bookmarks which syncs across all your Apple devices, this one appears only on the iOS device that you add it on.

To add a webpage bookmark on your iOS Home screen:

1. Open the webpage in Safari.

   [image]
2. Tap on the Share button. In the bottom row, tap on Add to Home Screen

   [image]
3. If needed, edit the name of shown below the bookmark icon. Webpage title is used by default.

   [image]
4. Tap Add and you are done. The webpage bookmark is now added to the iOS Home screen. If need be, it can be easily removed by following the same procedure to uninstall app (tap and hold until the icon wiggles, tap on ⓧ button at top left of the icon).

   [image]

Comment: Any idea if I can then open said app on the default browser and not Safari? I’m using Firefox.

Comment: @FredRocha I'm not using ios 14. See this article https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-firefox-widget-your-home-screen or ask a new question.